# In C, does a cast from char* to void* do anything?

Tags: c

Please have a look at the below mentioned code snippet and tell me the difference?

```
int main()
{
struct sockaddr_in serv_addr, cli_addr;
/* Initialize socket structure */
    bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
}
```

Now, what if i do something similar without typecasting `(char *)`, then also i feel it will do the same thing? Can someone clarify?

```
/* Initialize socket structure */
bzero( &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));
```

Comment: Please format your code using the code option next time :-)

Comment: Please edit your question so that the code is properly formatted (use the 101010 button and space over at least 4 spaces for each line).

Answer (score 4):

Since the first parameter is `void *`, you only need to cast in C++.

In C this is not necessary, as a `void *` was introduced<sup>1</sup> precisely so that you *wouldn't* need to cast it to or from other object<sup>2</sup> pointers. (Similarly with `malloc()` and other functions that deal with `void *`s)

---

1. In C89.
2. Any non-function pointer.

Comment: Emmm... why do I need to cast from `SomeType*` to `void*` in C++? Perhaps you meant that the reverse cast is required in C++, but not in C?

Comment: I mean that a conversion from `void *` to any other non-function pointer is implicit in C, and does not require a cast. In C++ this is no longer true.

Comment: Okay, where is `void*` converted to anything in this question? I only see a `SomeType*` to `void*` conversion.

Comment: The conversion happens during the call to bzero, as the first parameter is `void *`, but the passed argument is `struct sockaddr_in *`. Actually, it looks like his prototype may take a `char *` instead. Perhaps he has an old header file.

Comment: @sharptooth: in C++ the type checking is stricter.   And probably necessary since bzero could conceivably be overloaded so that bzero((void*)x, size) could call a different function to bzero((char*)x, size)

Comment: @Alex and JeremyP: what sharptooth is saying is that C++ is fine with an implicit cast *to* `void*` (just like C), which is what's happening in the code snippet.  Where C++ differs from C (in this area) is that it doesn't allow an implicit cast *from* `void*` - but that's not happening in the example.

Answer (score 2):

The cast is not needed, since [`bzero()`](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/bzero.html) accepts `void*` as the first argument and `AnyType*` can be implicitly converted to `void*`.